# Inserting NULL value to TIMESTAMP fields in postgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have the following DB schema in MySQL, which I have replicated in PostgreSQL using an ORM:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
id               BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXTVAL ('users_seq'),
email            VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
password         VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
last_name        VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
first_name       VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
created          TIMESTAMP(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
updated          TIMESTAMP(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

);

And I'm trying to execute the following query

```
INSERT INTO users (id, email, password,first_name, last_name, created, updated)
VALUES (1, 'user@gmail.com', 'pass', 'user', 'user', NULL, NULL);
```

This results in an error

```
ERROR:  null value in column "created" violates not-null constraint
```

Expected behaviour is to have the current timestamp in case the value is NULL, and it works in MySQL

I'm using PostgreSQL 10. Am I missing any configuration or is this not supported in Postgres?

Comment: remove postgres from tags please. if you want default value, skip the column from the list - if you explicitly specify `NULL` - it will inert NULL, not `DEFAULT`

Comment: allow null for `created` and `updated` fields, you are trying to insert null into non nullable  fields. Only default will will insert if your insert query don't have this field

Comment: @VaoTsun why remove postgres tag?. This is supported by mysql.  This query is generated from an ORM library.

Comment: Vao Tsun's confusion may be that you have said "I have this Postgres table definition", but the definition you gave is in MySQL syntax (backtick-quoted identifiers, `ENGINE = InnoDB`, etc). I have edited the question to say that this is the MySQL version you have replicated, but you might want to [edit] to provide the actual Postgres `CREATE TABLE` statement instead.

Answer (score 6):

`NULL` is not the same as "default".

When you specify `NULL` in your list of values to insert, Postgres will try to insert a `NULL` into that column of the table. If there is a constraint which prevents that from happening, such as a `NOT NULL` specifier on the column, the insert will fail.

If, however, you *do not specify* a value for that column, Postgres will insert the default value for that column, or `NULL` if no default is specified.

Consequently, since you have `DEFAULT` values on both of those columns you can write this:

```
INSERT INTO users (id, email, password,first_name, last_name)
VALUES (1, 'user@gmail.com', 'pass', 'user', 'user');
```

Which will effectively mean the same as this:

```
INSERT INTO users (id, email, password,first_name, last_name, created, updated)
VALUES (1, 'user@gmail.com', 'pass', 'user', 'user', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Note that it is perfectly legal to have a column which both accepts `NULL` and has a default value. If attempting to insert a `NULL` always inserted the default value, this would be impossible (or, at least, unnecessarily complicated).

Answer (score 1):

In case you dont want to set the default to current timestamp, you can consider using `-infinity` or `infinity` that way you can always find the data that had missing datetimes